# Android intent to restart app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities **LoginActivity (singleTask)** and **MainActivity (singleTop)**. The entry point of the app is the login activity. It checks if user credentials are available and then starts the main activity. After that the LoginActivity calls finish. This way I prevent the user from going back to login.

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

So the LoginActivity is cleared from the back stack. However I just discovered a disadvantage of calling finish:

When the users clicks on a notification I want to start the LoginActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

But the LoginActivity is not on the stack anymore (it was finished), so android will start a new instance of it. So it happens that there are two instances of the whole app. History:

```
(1) Login -> Main
(2) Main -> (Click on notification) -> Login -> Main
(3) Main -> Main -> (go back)
(4) Main
```

Since the LoginActivity is the entry point of my app, I cannot route the notification click to the MainActivity. Instead I would like the app to completely restart. Is this possible? Like:

```
(2) Main -> (Click on notification) -> Login -> Main
(3) Main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `LoginActivity`, after login process, you are calling `finish()` to `destroy` that activity.

But when user click to a notification that created from your `MainActivity`(switched from `LoginActivity`), you are redirecting again to `LoginActivity` that already logged user. Why don't you use a separate activity for it?

Also, If I were you, I would do this in authorization process.

```
App opened -> Main -> onCreate -> isNotLoggedIn -> switchToLoginActivity
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot do this by design. MainActivity is using a TabLayout and I want to keep my app modular and prevent putting login logic into main activity.

Comment: Ah, I am not saying put login logic to MainActivity. In manifest, start MainActivity first and if a user not loggedin, redirect to LoginActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to start your application in **(1)Main**, do the checking at startup and then spend **(2)Login**. Indeed, 99% of the time the person is authenticated and will not be directed to Login.

Your multiple instance problem and another problem regardless of your choice (Main/Login or Login/Main). You just don't show notifications when your application is active, but show an **internal message** like Dialog, Toast, Snack...

(Sorry for my english, I'm french).